# $modal causes page to freeze in IE11

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I use the following code snippet to show a simple modal:

```
$modal({
   title: 'My Title',
   template: 'path/to/my/simple.modal.html',
   show: true,
   scope: $scope
});
```

After closing the modal some parts of my webpage do not react to any events. In all other browsers this is working fine.

It's also really strange that I am not able to inspect some of the elements after closing the modal, all elements are shown as one single element (when using the Inspector-Tools in IE). After found one inspectable item, all the other items are getting inspectable as well. After inspecting for some moments, there is no freezed part again ... it's a really strange behaviour.

Does anybody else have this behaviour ? 
I am using Angular 1.5 and Angular-Strap 2.3.7.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: interesting. I have a similar problem going on in an angular-material project where my customer IE11 freezes so bad it locks up windows completely. I can't replicate the same problem in my virtual box. Although I'm not using angular-strap it's making me wonder if there is something common with your issue

Comment: That is really interesting. Which angular version are you using ? Is your complete page frozen or are there just some parts, which are not responding ? Are those parts insectable ?

Comment: Using 1.4.8. I can't see the machine this happens on that is using Windows 8.1 (not sure which subset) but have walked user through resetting browser default settings with add-ons disabled. Has been a problem for weeks and I even rewrote the app removing angular-material and used Materialize framework and it did same thing. Was usually caused in a modal also. Since you have similar situation using a completely different module starting to wonder if it is something in ngAnimate. However I have numerous other apps that same user has no problem with mostly using `ui-bootstrap`

Comment: As for freeze.... it completely freezes the whole windows OS and user has to do hard reboot each time. That's the part that totally amazes me. A browser freeze is one thing but freezing the whole OS is mind blowing. I use  virtual machine to test IE11 in windows 8.1 environment and can't replicate his problem

Comment: Am also using ui-router , ngSanitize ,ngAria,ngStorage and chart.js module and have swapped around several table modules as well. Curious what commonality all that may be with your app

Comment: @charlietfl : Why do you guess its something related with `ngAnimate` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sad, that there were no further hints on this.

I looked in the angular-strap bug-list for a solution and found one :

Just call `$destroy();` after hiding the modal did the trick for me.

Best !

Answer (score 0):

I Know this question is answered. but this is for share some info on that same issue.

Recently I also came across with that issue. In my case the reason was a CSS attribute **Display:block**. So after I turn the value from **block** to **none** my freezing error went off and it worked like a charm. So first right after you get that error check in Inspection whether the resulting div where the modal is loaded has a `style = "Display:block"` in it. If so remove it by a script or etc.

Hope this will help to improve this question.